# Setup WIFI ESP8266

Tags: c++, arduino, webserver, esp8266

I have small project on ESP8266.
Im creating web page for wifi connection.
I have problem with it.
For connection I have this method:

```
bool connect(String name, String password)
{
    WiFi.begin(name, password);
    if (WiFi.status() == WL_NO_SSID_AVAIL) return false;
    int timeout = 0;
    while (timeout < 5000)
    {
        if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED)
        {
            return true;
        }
        timeout+=500;
        delay(500);
    }
    return false;
}
```

And web server calls handler when I send data via form on webpage

```
void handleconnect()
{
    if (connect(webServer.arg("name"), webServer.arg("password")))
    {
        webServer.send(200, "text/html", "Success");
    }
    else
        webServer.send(200, "text/html", "Failed");
    }
}
```

I have problem when I send wrong password, at sometimes it works good and send Failed, but much often webserver call handler a few times and I have error. 
What I need to do to solve this problem? Thanks you!

Im using: NodeMCU, ESP8266WebServer, ESP8266WiFi, WiFiClient

Comment: "I have error" is not very useful information. Provide the error message! Please read [ask]

Comment: If I understand your code correctly, you use the connect function from the first listing in the "if" statement of the second listing. I'm no ESP Expert but is it possible that you reopen the wifi connection for web server in the connect method? If you use, webServer.send(...); which connection is used then?

Comment: you expect the TCP connection to live through WiFi reconnect?

Comment: Im using AP_STA mode

Comment: Error: when wrong password, browser dont get response from server and show error.

Answer (score 0):

First of all you cannot directly connect to network before that you need to disconnect from the existing network

Use EEPROM in esp8266

```
server.arg("myssid").toCharArray(WFSSID, 21);
server.arg("mypassword").toCharArray(WFPASS, 21);
EEPROM.put(WFSSID_ADDR, WFSSID);
EEPROM.put(WFPASS_ADDR, WFPASS);
EEPROM.commit();
delay(200);
EEPROM.get(WFSSID_ADDR, WFSSID);
EEPROM.get(WFPASS_ADDR, WFPASS);
```

Now after this either call

`ESP.restart();`

or

```
WiFi.disconnect();
delay(100);
WiFi.begin(WFSSID, WFPASS);
```

Best way is to use the ESP.restart() and then use before connecting to network always call WiFi.disconnect() as ESP has tendency to store old SSID and PASSWORD and tries to connect.

And for the webser use the MDNS

```
  MDNS.begin("esp8266");
  server.on( "/", handleRoot);
  server.begin();
```